# Use @EventListener annotation on multiple events in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, events, event-listener

This seems like a pretty straight forward question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

In Spring, I can create a listener for an event using the @EventListener annotation, like this:

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, what if I need the same method to listen to multiple events and act differently based the event that happens?

Intuitively, I'm thinking something similar to this:

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleEvents(ContextRefreshedEvent event, ContextStopped event) {
         String event;
         if(event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent)
              event = "Refreshed";
         if(event instanceof ContextStoppedEvent)
              event = "Stopped";
    }
}
```

What is the correct way for the EventListener annotation to listen to multiple events and how can the same method differentiate based on the actual event that happens?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-framework-eventlistener/)?

Comment: Are you looking to listen to custom events or spring events?

Comment: @IndraneelBende Mostly custom events

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's nominally easy to create an event listener that listens for multiple events:

```
@EventListener({EventA.class, EventB.class})
public doSomething() {
   ...
}
```

But obviously this approach does not give you access to the underlying event. Based on the javadoc for `EventListener` it does not appear to be possible to do what you are suggesting

> If an annotated method supports a single event type, the method may
>   declare a single parameter that reflects the event type to listen to.
>   If an annotated method supports multiple event types, this annotation
>   may refer to one or more supported event types using the classes
>   attribute. See the classes() javadoc for further details.
>
> ...
>
> If (the
>   `classes`) attribute is specified with a single value, the annotated
>   method may optionally accept a single parameter. However, if this
>   attribute is specified with multiple values, the annotated method must
>   not declare any parameters.

Thus there does not appear to be any mechanism to consume multiple events and take a different action based on the body of those events. I would suggest that this shouldn't be necessary though, you could always register event-specific `@EventListener` methods, and then just have them call a shared method to perform any common functionality.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html

Answer (score 10):

Since Spring 4.2 you can use subclass in method declaration to handle all events those extends this subclass:

```
@EventListener
public void handleEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
  // listen all descendants of the ApplicationEvent
}
```

**UPDATE 2020-10-07:

NOTE: Solution below works but contradicts with official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html#classes--) and may stop working in next Spring releases.**
Also you can narrow list of events by using annotion's attribute:

```
@EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class, ApplicationReadyEvent.class})
public void handleEvent(Object event) {
  // listen only ContextRefreshedEvent and ApplicationReadyEvent
}
```

Comment: The answer is not correct. .....if this attribute is specified with multiple values, the annotated method must not declare any parameters.   https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html#classes--

Comment: @wakedeer I added a warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you do something like this.

From `SpringFramework 4.2`, you can publish events without extending `ApplicationEvent`.

As you replied you want to mostly listen to custom events. You can do something like this.

Create a Base class called `BaseEvent`.

```
public class BaseEvent {

  private String type;

  public BaseEvent() {}

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

Consider that as the base class whenever you want to publish a custom `Event`.

Now lets create two custom events called `Example1Event` and `Example2Event`.

`Example1Event` Class

```
public class Example1Event extends BaseEvent {

  private String message;

  public Example1Event() {}

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

`Example2Event` Class

```
public class Example2Event extends BaseEvent {

  private String message;

  public Example2Event() {}

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

Your `EventListener` would look like this.

```
public class EventReceiver {

  public EventReceiver() {}

  @EventListener
  public void receiveEvent(BaseEvent event) {
    String eventType = event.getType();
    if (eventType.equals("example1")) {
      Example1Event example1Event = (Example1Event) event;
      System.out.println(example1Event.getMessage());
    } else if (eventType.equals("example2")) {
      Example2Event example2Event = (Example2Event) event;
      System.out.println(example2Event.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

This will work for what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple EventListener for each separate event.