# Is it possible for my Spring EventListener to wait for 2 events to progress?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a `SpringBoot` application and have to connect to a websocket server to receive messages, which my application then processes internally using an inbuilt `FinitStateMachine` (FSM).

What I want is to start the connect() call to the websocket server only after:

1. my spring application has initialized
2. my FSM builder has completed the build() call

I have used Spring's `ApplicationEventPublisher` to publish a custom event (`FSMInitializedEvent`) when my FSM is built. And the code which initiates connection to websocket server waits for this custom event, but I want my websocket connector code to ALSO wait for Spring's `ApplicationReadyEvent`. Is there a neat way to do this?

From my FSM's build():

```
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent( new FSMInitializedEvent() );
```

Within my WebSocket connector class:

```
@EventListener(FSMInitializedEvent.class) <-- HERE i want to listen for this other event too before progressing - ApplicationReadyEvent.class
    public void init() {
// code to initiate the connection
}
```

I could programmatically handle this but looking for some ready to use elegant solution. Also, my question is different what's been suggested here: [Use @EventListener annotation on multiple events in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884537/use-eventlistener-annotation-on-multiple-events-in-spring), as I want my listener to **wait** for multiple events to have happened as a precondition, before proceeding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use @EventListener annotation on multiple events in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884537/use-eventlistener-annotation-on-multiple-events-in-spring)

Comment: @pvpkiran I looked into the link you commented. I think my question is different. I need to know if my listener could wait for both events to have arrived before proceeding. The link is more about being able to handle multiple events within the same listener - but it's not about waiting for multiple events to have happened as a precondition before proceeding.