# Automatically log Application Events

Tags: spring-boot, logging

In my application I have multiple custom Spring Application Events. I want to log every instance of these events occurring. Is there a way to do this automatically or do I have to manually log it every time?

Answer (score 0):

You might create an event listener for the type of events you're interested in and log the event. Spring will register this listener and you'll basically done:

```
@Component
public class CustomEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomEvent> {

    private static final Logger logger = ...;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomEvent event) {
       LOGGER.info("Got event: {}" , event);
    }
}
```

However, you can't really use the same listener subscribed to multiple **types** of event unless they have an hierarchy (inheritance from some base event) You might be interested to read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884537/use-eventlistener-annotation-on-multiple-events-in-spring) it provides technical solutions in various cases.